# Memory is leaking for Postgres in Docker

Tags: postgresql, memory, docker-compose, loading

I make loading testing for companies service.
Compose version: `Docker Compose version v2.4.1`
My compose for DB:

```
version: '3.4'
x-check: &default-healthcheck
  healthcheck:
    test: [ "CMD", "/data/.prepare" ]
    interval: 30s
    timeout: 30s

services:
  postgres-api:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: 'load-POSTGRES-API'
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
    command: [
      "postgres",
      "-c",
      "log_statement=all",
      "-c",
      "log_destination=stderr",
      "-c",
      "max_connections=50",
      "-c",
      "shared_buffers=1GB",
      "-c",
      "effective_cache_size=4GB",
      "-c",
      "work_mem=16MB",
      "-c",
      "maintenance_work_mem=512MB",
      "-c",
      "random_page_cost=1.1",
      "-c",
      "temp_file_limit=10GB",
      "-c",
      "log_min_duration_statement=200ms",
      "-c",
      "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=10s",
      "-c",
      "lock_timeout=1s",
      "-c",
      "statement_timeout=60s",
      "-c",
      "shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements",
      "-c",
      "pg_stat_statements.max=10000",
      "-c",
      "pg_stat_statements.track=all"
    ]
    ports:
      - "${EXT_IP}:${POSTGRES_EXPOSE_API}"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-l3/data:/data:rw
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
        reservations:
          memory: 256M
    <<: *default-healthcheck
```

The allocated memory lasts for 5-10 minutes (depending on the load), then an overflow occurs, the services will not connect to the database and I observe an error:

```
"message":"the database system is in recovery mode"
```

Connections are lost, the database memory is cleared and starts to melt quickly again.
The size of all tables is ~50Mb.

How can this be solved? How normal is it?

Comment: You'll need to describe the problem in more detail - "The allocated memory" and "overflow occurs" doesn't tell us enough. Do you have restrictions on the memory available to the container and if so how much? What is in charge of maintaining the memory limits and how is it configured?

Comment: @RichardHuxton limit for a container with a postgres = 4GB.
I configure everything via docker-compose file, total volume for Docker = 16Gb

Comment: How do you know an overflow occurs?  Please quote the error message that indicates that.